# How could I align these three bottom divs to rise up?

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in CSS and HTML and I am currently just trying to make the skin of the calculator model for my homework.

`.row-three {display: inline-block;}`

https://codepen.io/jmv_chin/pen/XQWzYK

How can I align the three bottom divs to rise up with the other numbers?

Any positive criticism is helpful!

Comment: Please add the code here and not through a link. I'd suggest looking for ways to bring the overall layout to a higher level. Think of the calculator as areas, main number pad, in/out screen, etc., then mark it up that way as opposed to every individual element, of row three for example, taking on a shared style.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need add that two lines to

```
#equal {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you that worked! Once I get it looking like somewhat of the face of a calculator I'll be working on Javascript to function them as one! :)